# Add a new element to each element of a list using lapply

Tags: r

I have some code that needs to be as fast as possible. There is one section where I set up a list using a for() loop like this (the real version is adding a bunch of other things but it's all roughly equivalent to this):

```
N0 <- 3
ind <- vector(mode="list", N0) # Empty list with N0 elements
for(i in seq(ind)){
  ind[[i]]$alive <- 1 # 1 = alive, 0 = dead
  ind[[i]]$sex <- sample(c("F","M"),1) # F = female, M = male
}
```

This returns a list like this:

```
> str(ind)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ alive: num 1
  ..$ sex  : chr "M"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ alive: num 1
  ..$ sex  : chr "F"
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ alive: num 1
  ..$ sex  : chr "F"
```

I am trying to work out a way to do this using lapply. I'm sure there's something really simple that will fix it but I just can't work it out. If anyone can enlighten me I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```r
ind <- lapply(seq(N0), function(x) list(alive = 1, sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 1)))
str(ind)
#> List of 3
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ alive: num 1
#>   ..$ sex  : chr "M"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ alive: num 1
#>   ..$ sex  : chr "F"
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ alive: num 1
#>   ..$ sex  : chr "M"
```

Comment: Yes, like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(seq(N0), ~ list(alive = 1, sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 1)))
```

Comment: Yes... except that runs about 50% slower than the loop does.